Create two azure fnuctions with same route but one have params and another one doesn't have
This is my function file:
[Function("AssetList")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAssetList([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "api/cdp")] HttpRequest req, [FromQuery] string offset)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("asset list");
}

[Function("Asset")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsset([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "api/cdp/{*guid}")] HttpRequest req, string guid)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("asset");
}

while im calling "'http://localhost:7075/interKonnect/cdp'" this url its triggering GetAsset function only
what my requirement is trigger this function while call "http://localhost:7075/interKonnect/cdp"
trigger GetAssetList funtion
if i call "http://localhost:7075/interKonnect/cdp/8933" it must trigger GetAsset function


Use {guid} instead of {*guid} in the Route of Azure function.

I am able to run two azure functions with same route using below code, one with guid as parameter and another one without any parameters.
[Function("AssetList")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAssetList([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "api/cdp")] HttpRequest req, [FromQuery] string offset)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("asset list");
}
[Function("Asset")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsset([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "api/cdp/{guid}")] HttpRequest req, string guid)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("asset");
}


Able to run the functions and got the expected response:

Functions:

        Asset: [GET] http://localhost:7193/api/api/cdp/{guid}

        AssetList: [GET] http://localhost:7193/api/api/cdp

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-21T06:59:27.061Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-08-21T07:00:56.294Z] Executing 'Functions.AssetList' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d56acff0-9155-41e7-b868-301583931fee)
[2024-08-21T07:01:01.228Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-21T07:01:01.234Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-08-21T07:01:01.351Z] Executed 'Functions.AssetList' (Succeeded, Id=d56acff0-9155-41e7-b868-301583931fee, Duration=5089ms)
[2024-08-21T07:01:19.163Z] Executing 'Functions.Asset' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=e61a2dc8-2837-41ba-92a3-75c67aee0ab7)
[2024-08-21T07:01:19.189Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-21T07:01:19.190Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-08-21T07:01:19.197Z] Executed 'Functions.Asset' (Succeeded, Id=e61a2dc8-2837-41ba-92a3-75c67aee0ab7, Duration=35ms)

http://localhost:7193/api/api/cdp/{guid}:

http://localhost:7193/api/api/cdp:

